# MongoDB error callback handling for rollback feature

Tags: mongodb, error-handling, rollback

Now I'm developing the full-featured e-commerce system with angularjs, expressjs and MongoDB. MongoDB is not provide the transaction query. So I use the "Two phase commit" for inventory system and payment system.

But I have a question in the MongoDB error handling. In the "Two phase commit", if some failure or error occurs after first query success, then rollback first query. But if an other error occur in rollback query, then  rollback can not be ensured. Below is my server side code with expressjs.

At first put the item into user's cart and update product document ( update the carted information ).
if error occur at update product document query, then pull item from user's cart ( this is rollback process ).

But in rollback process ( in this case, $pull query ), if error callback is called, then rollback process failed.

Are there any reasonable method for rollback??

```
var userID = new ObjectID(Session.get(req, 'userId'));
var variantID = new ObjectID(body.variantID);
var quantity = Number(body.qty);
Cart.put(userID, variantID, quantity, body.detail).then(function(rs){
  if(rs.result.n == 0){
    Response.toJson(res, Code.EXIST_IN_CART, 'The product with this variant is already exist in your cart!', {});
  }else{
    Variant.carted(userID, variantID, quantity).then(function(rs){
      Response.toJson(res, Code.SUCCESS, 'Putting the product with a specific variant into your cart is success', {});
      }, function(){
        Cart.pull(userID, variantID).then(function(){
          Response.toJson(res, Code.FAILED, 'Failed to put item into your cart! Check stock or database exception!', {});
        }, function(){
          Response.toJson(res, Code.ROLLBACK_FAILED, 'Rollback process is failed!', {});
      });
    });
  }
}, Response.dbErrorCallback(res));
```

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev update with my code

Comment: yep, better. Only use "code sample" button in these cases, not "code snippet".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev update to "code sample"

Comment: I did that before my comment :)